# BizTalk WCF-Custom Behavior Extension not showing up

Tags: biztalk, endpoint, behavior, biztalk-2013

I have made the following behavior extension:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel.Configuration;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Discovery;

namespace Residence.WCFEndpointBehavior
{
    namespace Residence.WCFEndpointBehavior
    {
        public class MustUnderstandValidationOffElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
        {
            protected override object CreateBehavior()
            {
                return new MustUnderstandBehavior(false);
            }

            public override Type BehaviorType
            {
                get
                {
                    return typeof(MustUnderstandBehavior);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting assembly name is MustUnderstandValidationOffElement.

Version is 1.1.0.0

I put the assembly in the GAC.

```
GacUtil /lr MustUnderstandValidationOffElement
```

returns

> MustUnderstandValidationOffElement, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5f1263db97cf42d0, processorArchitecture=MSIL

In BizTalk 2013 R2 I open the WCF-Custom adapter for the relevant host name and import:

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<extensions>
<behaviorExtensions>
  <add name="mustUnderstandValidationOffElement" type="Residence.WCFEndpointBehavior.MustUnderstandValidationOffElement, MustUnderstandValidationOffElement, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5f1263db97cf42d0"/>
</behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

in WCF-Custom Transport Properties.

Next I restart the host instance of the host.

I close the BizTalk Server Administration Console and open it again.

Next I open properties for the SendPort using the WCF-Custom adapter in the host -> Click configure and choose Bindings.
I right click EndpointBehavior and select Add extension.

Alas - my "mustUnderstandValidationOffElement" does not show up in the list.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to add entries to the machine.config files for it.

Comment: Putting it in the machine.config files would alter the behavior on all WCF-Custom adapters. As I understand this is exactly the reason that BizTalk 2013 supports it.

Comment: https://azurebiztalkread.wordpress.com/2019/03/23/register-wcf-custom-behavior-in-biztalk-itself/

Comment: Thanks Dijkgraaf! Did see this already - to no avail, though

Comment: Adding it to the machine.config should not alter the behavior of all the WCF-Custom adapters, only those where you select it in the End Point Behavior for that port.  The exception your code does something that alters the behavior for everything running in that context, e.g. Setting the TLS version `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`  This can be mitigated by running that port in a separate host instance from those you don't want to be impacted.

Comment: Get your point Dijkgraaf - only the ports where the endpoint behavior is selected get altered. My bad. I tried your suggestion and added the entries to all 4 machine.configs, rebooted the server, but still no luck. The behavior was still missing from the list.

Comment: That usually happens if either the name, the assembly version or the strong name key doesn't match.  Double check those.

Comment: Having the exact problem...but your answer does not apply to me. BizTalk 2020?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dijkgraaf for directing me to the solution. After creating a new specific strong name key for signing my endpoint behavior, it appeared in the Add extension list!

It worked without configuring the machine.config's

**BUT** Adding this behavior to the sendport did NOT prevent the sending of mustUnderstand=1 to the remote server. Instead it seems to make our Biztalk server ignore any mustUnderstand=1 i.e. quite the reverse of what we need.